# How to make box-shadow inside transparent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

When the element is transparent, the shadow isn't inside that element. Look at this example:

```css
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yrqvdbux/6/

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;height:100%; margin:0;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bg {
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-color:#33FF55;
}

.shadow {
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px; left:100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

How to make the shadow inside the box?
When i add background-color property it looks quite good, but look at the corners, it doesn't fit.

https://jsfiddle.net/y8o47pm9/5/

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;height:100%; margin:0;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bg {
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-color:#33FF55;
}

.shadow {
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px; left:100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="shadow">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use `box-shadow` property with `inset` value

Comment: `box-shadow:inset  0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` like this

Answer (score 0):

Use inset to make the shadow inside the box.
Replace the `box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` with `box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;height:100%; margin:0;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bg {
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-color:#33FF55;
}

.shadow {
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px; left:100px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```